# HTML jLabel and form height

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have Dialog which contains **jLabel formatted with html** (As a security mea...).

My english is bad, so screenshots:
[image: NetBeans Form Editor]
NetBeans Form Editor
[image: Compiled result]
Compiled result

How to fix this issue or how to make jLabel auto-height without html?

**EDIT:**
jLabel is translatable and should be with normal height with any text.

**EDIT2:**
Added screenshot and forgot to specify which jLabel is HTML, As a security mea...
[image: Form]
Form

Comment: don't to use GUI builder, otherwise JFrame.pack() haven't effect without bunch of code lines

Comment: I'm a little surprised this failed, despite the HTML.  What is the code?

Comment: What code? :P If you are about source code, its not edited, default generated by NetBeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      pack();
   }
});
```

One more pack fixed this issue.